# Animate scroll to loaded element

Tags: reactjs, react-virtualized

I'm using a `List` inside of `InfiniteLoader`. Is it possible to animate the scroll to a specific element that's been loaded?

I think the animation is important as it gives the list time to calculate the height of each row.

I've tried using `scrollToPosition` on the list but it doesn't calculate the rows above. So when the use scroll up, the items jump about.

Comment: you can use the [scroll-to-element](https://www.npmjs.com/package/scroll-to-element) library. it supports easing.

Comment: I don’t think that will work. The list is virtualised so the element won’t necessarily exist.

Comment: how can you scroll not a none existing node then?

Comment: Keep scrolling and eventually it will exist. Then stop. In fact, maybe I’ll do that.

Comment: So using this library (or any other scrolling solution) your target is `currentItem || lastItem`